# How to use map to print a List in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Sorry if I am being silly but I am a beginner in Haskell ans I am trying to make a print a List with putStrLn but i am not sure how to solve the next problem:

And I am trying to made a basic print List in Haskell with the code:

```
import System.IO

array = map show [1, 2, 3, 4]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  map putStrLn array
```

but the compiler give me:

```
 8 main.hs:7:3: error:                                                                                                          
  7     • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘[IO ()]’                                                            
  6     • In a stmt of a 'do' block: map putStrLn array                                                                              
  5       In the expression: do map putStrLn array                                                                                   
  4       In an equation for ‘main’: main = do map putStrLn array
```

How I should fix it?

Comment: You are mapping over a list, not an array. What is map's type? What is putStrLn's type?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I wiil rectify the Array/list, but puStrLn Type in defined in the System.IO standard module. (It should be String -> IO ())

Comment: Use `traverse` instead -- it's like `map` but for monadic actions like `putStrLn`

Comment: @luqui 1. How is defined traverse?, 2. not the error is Couldn't match type ‘[()]’ with ‘()’                                                                                       
  8       Expected type: IO ()                                                                                                       
  7         Actual type: IO [()]   
3. I just change map with traverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell handles IO quite differently than other languages.

In a language like Java, `System.Out.println(3)` is a statement which does not evaluate to a value, so you can't even write something like `x = System.Out.println(3);`.

In a language like Lisp, `(print 3)` evaluates to 3 and, in the process of evaluation, prints `3`. So saying something like `(setq x (print 3))` will set the value of `x` to `3` and also print `3`.

In Haskell, `putStrLn "3"` represents the command to print `3`. Thus, saying `x = putStrLn "3"` does absolutely nothing except assign `x` to the command `putStrLn "3"`.

Let's look at some types. We have

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Thus, we should have

```hs
map putStrLn :: [String] -> [IO ()]
map putStrLn array :: [IO ()]
```

In other words, `map putStrLn array` is a list of "IO actions" which result in a value of type `()` (basically, this means that executing the actions results in no extra information).

However, in order to write

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = map putStrLn array
```

which is what

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do map putStrLn array
```

translates to, we need `map putStrLn` to be of type `IO ()`, NOT of type `[IO ()]`.

If you wish to execute an action for each element of a list, you can use the `for_` function, which has type `for_ :: (Foldable g, Applicative f) => g a -> (a -> f ()) -> f ()`. `IO` is `Applicative` and `[]` is `Foldable`, so in particular `for_ :: [String] -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO ()` is one type that `for_` can take. The code looks like

```hs
import Data.Foldable (for_)

array :: [String]
array = map show [1, 2, 3, 4]

main :: IO ()
main = for_ array putStrLn
```

This would be equivalent in an imperative language to

```
for each x in array do {
    putStrLn x;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any lisp where `(print 3)` evaluates to 3. *Maybe* in some it evaluates to `"3"`, but usually it evaluates to nil, the local equivalent of `()`.

Comment: @amalloy In common lisp, `(print 3)` evaluates to 3. Try `(let ((x (print 3))) (= x 3))`, for example.